# String argument behaves differently within my script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried to parse a text out of some html elements using [string argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) the way it is described here but failed miserably. I've tried two different ways but every time I encountered the same `AttributeError`.

***How can I use string argument in this very case to fetch the text?***

I've tried with:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlelement = """
<caption>
    <span class="toggle open"></span>
    ASIC registration
</caption>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlelement,"lxml")
try:
    item = soup.find("caption",string="ASIC registration").text
    #item = soup.find("caption",string=re.compile("ASIC registration",re.I)).text
except AttributeError:
    item = ""
print(item)
```

Expected output (`only using string argument`):

```
ASIC registration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use string argument in this very case to fetch the text?

**You can't**

Note: 
I am assuming that you mean by some change string parameter in

```
item = soup.find("caption",string="ASIC registration").text
```

As given in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)

> If a tag has only one child, and that child is a NavigableString, the
>   child is made available as .string:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlelement = """
<caption>
    <span class="toggle open"></span>
    ASIC registration
</caption>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlelement,"lxml")
item = soup.find("caption")
print(item.string)
```

Output

```
None
```

Here the `.string` is `None` as caption has more than one child.

If you are trying to get the parent (caption tag in this case) with the text, you could do

```
item = soup.find(string=re.compile('ASIC registration')).parent
```

which will give

```
<caption><a></a>ASIC registration</caption>
```

Of course, calling a `.text` on this parent tag will give the full text within that tag, if it is not the full text within it.

```
item = soup.find(string=re.compile('ASIC')).parent.text
```

will give an output

```
ASIC registration
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're running into is that the string argument searches for strings instead of for tags as it states in the documentation you linked.

The syntax you are using:

```
soup.find("caption",string="ASIC registration")
```

is for finding tags.

For finding strings:

```
soup.find(string=re.compile('ASIC'))
```

With the first one you are saying find a caption tag with the "string" attribute of your string.  The caption tag has no string attribute so nothing is returned.

The second one is saying find the string that contains 'ASIC', so it returns the string.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the string parameter doesn't work if a tag has a child tag. The following code is stupid, but it works:

```
real_item = ""
try:
    items = soup.find_all("caption")
    r = re.compile(u"ASIC registration", re.I)
    for item in items:
        for s in item.strings:
            if r.search(unicode(s)):
                real_item = item
                break

except AttributeError:
    real_item = ""
print(real_item)
```

Comment: With this method would it be more efficient to do `real_item = item if item.find(string=r) else None`? Then break if real_item instead of the second loop?  Also, you'd need the break if real_item in the outer loop anyway with your current setup.

Comment: Maybe? I just created something that works, performance is a different question.